# add triggers in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm working on users and permissions Module for some projects using c# 4.0 and Entities Framework.

and in the proposed scenario, i have to give users permissions on data like:

- give user "John" management permission for employees in specific department.

so I thought to handle this permission in Entity Framework and add some conditions on all select queries before execute it ,In other words i need to add somethings like trigger in entity framework to alter select query before execute it.

is there any way to do that in entity framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple conditions to `IQueryable` dynamically. So you can do something like:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="DepartmentManager")]
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetManagedEmployees()
{
  // build base query
  var query = from e in context.Employees
              select e;

  // add condition
  query = AddDepartmentPermissions(query);
  return query.AsEnumerable();
}
```

And your `AddDepartmentPermissions` will look like:

```
private IQueryable<Employee> AddDepartmentPermission(IQueryable<Employee> query)
{
  int departmentId = GetAllowedDepartmentSomewhere();
  return query.Where(e => e.Department.Id == departmentId);
}
```

This is just an example where `PrincipalPermission` don't allow calling `GetManagedEmployees` for non manager roles and `AddDepartmentPermission` adds query part for selection employees only from allowed department.

The main point is that you can wrap `IQueryable<T>` to methods which will modify query. I believe it should be even possible to add Interception (aspects) directly to properties exposing `ObjectSet` and dynamically add query parts dealing with security.